# Getting documents matched in a specific hour range from a date field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with mapping in the form :

```
        "mappings": {
                    "created_time" :{
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "user_id": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to find all users that were Created between a certain hour range, lets say 10-12pm.

I'm not sure how to go about it i read about all kinds of aggregations and nothing seem to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use something called [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html).

It would look like this:

```
query: {
      bool: {
          "filter": {
              "script": {
                   "script": {
                      "source": "doc['created_time'].getHourOfDay() >= min && doc['created_time'].getHourOfDay() < max",
                      "lang": "expression",
                      "params": {
                        "min": 10,
                        "max": 12
                      }
                   }
             }
       }
}
```

This will give you the required hits.